# Mono.Cecil - simple example how to get method body

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection, mono.cecil

I have been searching for a newbie question, but can't find a simple example.
Can anyone give me a simple example how to get MethodBody into most available string result? Like:

```
using Mono.Cecil;
using Mono.Cecil.Cil;

namespace my
{
    public class Main
    {
        public Main()
        {
             // phseudo code, but doesnt work
            Console.Write(    getMethod("HelloWorld").GetMethodBody().ToString()   );
        }

        public void HelloWorld(){
             MessageBox.Show("Hiiiiiiiiii");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of string result do you need or expect? IL bytecode in hex? Human readable IL instructions? ...?

Comment: @thehennyy I want Human-readable. I know it won't be 100% perfect, but whatever maximum is possible.

Comment: Is `ildasm` an option? Otherwise you should find some code how to get the method body using mono.cecil. From there you can just loop through the `Instruction`-objects, i think they support `ToString()`

Comment: @thehennyy mate, that's what I ask. I couldnt find and that's why I asked here - I am not C# pro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with reading your assembly:

```
var path = "... path to your assembly ...";
var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(path);
```

You can use `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName` as `path` if you want to open running process

Now get all types and methods wich you want to inspect

```
var toInspect = assembly.MainModule
  .GetTypes()
  .SelectMany(t => t.Methods
      .Where(m => m.HasBody)
      .Select(m => new {t, m}))
```

If you already knew type and method names you can modify your query something like this:

```
toInspect = toInspect.Where(x => x.t.Name.EndsWith("Main") && x.m.Name == "HelloWorld");
```

After that just iterate over that collection:

```
foreach (var method in toInspect)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\tType = {method.t.Name}\n\t\tMethod = {method.m.Name}");
    foreach (var instruction in method.m.Body.Instructions)
        Console.WriteLine($"{instruction.OpCode} \"{instruction.Operand}\"");
}
```

Output will be

```
Type = Main
  Method = HelloWorld

ldstr "Hiiiiiiiiii"
call "System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox::Show(System.String)"
pop ""
ret ""
```

Comment: Aleks, many thanks for the excellent answer, i have upvoted and marked it on its time. however, my question, can you give me a version without using linq  when you define `toInspect` object (so, without "selectMany & where" commands) ? thanks