# Finding a specific method via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Let's say we have two public methods within a class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public bool DoSomething(int param1)
    {
        return param1 == 30;
    }

    public bool DoSomethingElse(int param1)
    {
        param1 *= 2;
        return param1 == 30;
    }
}
```

I could write the following code to get both of these methods using reflection:

```
MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(SomeClass).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                       .Where(x => x.ReturnType == typeof(bool)
                              && x.GetParameters().Length == 1
                              && x.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(int)).ToArray();
```

Let's say I only wanted `DoSomethingElse`, I could just use `methods[1]`.

However, let's say they swapped places the next time this class is compiled. I would end up with `DoSomething` instead.

The only thing that separates these two methods, is that `DoSomethingElse` multiplies the parameters by 2 before checking.

Are there any other checks I can do with reflection to ensure I always get `DoSomethingElse`?

**Note: The methods I'm looking for may have their names changed each time it is compiled, so simply searching for their name won't work either.**

Comment: You could decorate the method with a custom `Attribute`, then use LINQ to check the methods for that attribute.

Comment: @AlphaDelta I'm not the one writing the source code. I don't have control over that.

Comment: I don't see anyway to do this with simple C# reflection. Maybe a usecase for [Cecil](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/).
A simple example that could fit your usage : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923757/mono-cecil-simple-example-how-to-get-method-body

Comment: There are many things you could check, such as the method signature (parameters), return type, or even an analysis of the IL code of the method itself. But I'm not sure what you're asking is possible, given you aren't in control of the source; all potential metadata is mutable.

Comment: The actual question here is what metadata stays **constant**. If you can asnwer that, you can answer your question. We can´t.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I think you might be right. I don't think it's possible with simple reflection.

Comment: Invoke them both with `30` and see which ends up returning true? But jokes aside, if there isn't anything logical or constant I really can't see a way to determine which is which.

Comment: I don't know what are you really trying to do but reflection give you only the metadata about the method and not the implementation details(lines of code). You can add custom attribute to the method.

Comment: @lior reflection enables reading the source code as it was originaly (the compiler may have optimized some of the code though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you can analyze methods' **IL code**; let's check if we have a `* 2` within first `10` IL codes:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions

**Code:**

```
  MethodInfo[] methods = GetType()
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Where(x => x.ReturnType == typeof(bool)
           && x.GetParameters().Length == 1
           && x.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(int))
    .Where(m => m
       .GetMethodBody()
       .GetILAsByteArray()
       .Take(10)                  // take first 10 IL codes
       .SkipWhile(b => b != 0x18) // ldc.i4.2 : load 2
       .Any(b => b == 0x5A))      // mul      : multiply 
    .ToArray();
```

let's have a look:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, methods.Select(m => m.Name)));
```

**Outcome:**

```
  DoSomethingElse
```

however, I strongly recommend either use specific method `Name` or mark method with an *attribute* etc.